# how to use addPreferencesFromResource for android 2.X?

Tags: android, deprecated, android-preferences

Followed several howto but I can't understand,
how to use  `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)` because is deprecated.

The best way is to use the `fragment` but fragments are available only later 3.0, I need to do for android version 2.x

Which way I'll follow?

Comment: how did you solve it @PolHallen?

Answer (score 4):

In Android, "deprecated" means "we have another solution that we think that you should consider". Particularly, for situations like this, you have no choice but to use `addPreferencesFromResource()` on Android 2.x, as `onBuildHeaders()` (the approach used in API Level 11+) does not exist.

You can create code that supports both:

```
public class EditPreferences extends SherlockPreferenceActivity {
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences2);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
  }
}
```

Here, we use `onBuildHeaders()` for API Level 11+ and `addPreferencesFromResource()` on API Level 10 and below. [Here is the complete sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC) from which this code was pulled.